# SQL Query "like" operator error, when the field is null

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-like, sql-null

this query returns 421 records:

[image: this query returns 421 records]

Now when I implement the "like" operator, it returns 349 records, it is not taking into account the records with the field "invoice_number" in null:

[image: Now when I implement the "like" operator, it returns 349 records, it is not taking into account the records with the field "invoice_number" in null]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A condition like `null like '%%'` is false. `null` is not `like` anything. So if you want to allow `null` values, you need to be explicit about it:

```
and (ds.numero_factura like '%%' or ds.numero_factura is null)
```

Or you can use `coalesce()`:

```
 and coalesce(ds.numero_factura, '') like '%%'
```

This condition does not really make sense though (basically it will allow all records), so you would need to adapt it to your exact use case.

Another remark is that `ds.numero_factura` looks like a number; in that case, you don't want to use string functions on it: use number functions instead.